# Elasticsearch nested objects with query_string as first class attributes

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to index a nested field as a first-class attribute in my document so that I can search them using `query_string` without dot syntax.
For example, if I have a document like 
`"data": { "name": "Bob" }` 
instead of searching for `data.name:Bob` I would like to be able to search for `name:Bob`

The root of my issue is that we index a jsonb column that may have varying attributes. In some instances the data property may contain a `data.business` attribute, etc. I would like users to be able to search on these attributes without needing to "dig" into the object.

The `data` field does not have to be indexed as a nested type unless necessary; I was indexing it as an object previously.

I have tried to leverage the `_all` field as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978504/elasticsearch-nested-object-query-string).

I have also tried to use `include_in_parent:true` and set the datatype as `nested` for my `data` field as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415456/elasticsearch-query-string-nested-query).

I have also looked into the `inner_hits` feature to no avail.

Here's an example of my mapping for the data attribute.

```
PUT my_index

{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "data": {
          "type": "object"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example document

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1

{
  "data": {
    name: "bob",
    business: "None of yours"
  }
}
```

And how my query currently looks:

```
GET my_index/_search

{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "name:bob",
      "fields": ["data.*"]
    }
  }
}
```

With the current setup I almost get my desired results. I can search on individual properties like `data.name:bob` and `data.business:"None of yours"` and get back the correct documents.
However I want to be able to get the exact same results with `business:"None of yours"` or `name:bob`.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html). For anyone coming across this in the future, here is how I solved the issue:
I used `path_match` to match the data object (`data.*`).
Then using `copy_to` and `{name}` I dynamically created top-level fields on my parent object.

```
{
  "dynamic_templates":[
    {"template_1":
       {"mapping":
          {"copy_to":"{name}"},
        "path_match":"data.*"
       }
     }
   ]
}
```